# Hiding countdown when game is paused restarts it when game is resumed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can pause my game both during gameplay and the pre-gameplay countdown (3, 2, 1) - both are tracked inside the GameManager as `UserIsPlaying`, only the countdown is tracked as `CountdownIsOn` as well (as you will see in the script snippets).

The issue I'm facing is that whenever I'm pausing the game during the countdown and then resume, the countdown restarts (I believe this is due to the fact that I'm hiding it as a gameobject and that gameobject has the Countdown script attached to it).

Here's the relevant part of my PauseMenu script (I'm doing the opposite in the `Resume` public void counterpart of the same script).

```
public GameObject pauseMenuUI;
public GameObject hidePauseButtonPM;

public GameObject hidePlayer;
public GameObject hideCountdownPause;

public void Pause ()
{        
    pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
    hidePauseButtonPM.SetActive(false);

    if (GameManager.CountdownIsOn)
    {
        hidePlayer.SetActive(false);
        hideCountdownPause.SetActive(false); 

    }
    if (GameManager.UserIsPlaying && !GameManager.CountdownIsOn)
    {
        hidePlayer.SetActive(false);                        
    }

    Time.timeScale = 0f;
    GameIsPaused = true;
}
```

This is my Countdown script.

```
public Color color3;     
public Color color2;
public Color color1;

Text countdown;    

void OnEnable()
{
    countdown = GetComponent<Text>();
    countdown.text = "3";        
    StartCoroutine("Countdown");
}

IEnumerator Countdown()
{
    int count = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        countdown.text = (count - i).ToString();            
        if ((count - i) == 3)
        {
            countdown.color = color3;                
        }
        if ((count - i) == 2)
        {
            countdown.color = color2;                
        }
        if ((count - i) == 1)
        {
            countdown.color = color1;                
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);            
    }
    StartRound();
}
```

So my question to you is: how do I hide the countdown during `Pause`so that it won't restart on `Resume`?

Thought (and tried to no avail) of changing the Countdown text's alpha to 0 when the game is paused and back to 255 once resuming. Also tried to attach my Countdown script to my Main Camera and changing `Text countdown;` to `public Text countdown;` so I can feed my Countdown text to it, but nothing.

Comment: `OnEnable() { StartCoroutine("Countdown"); }` Hmmm On Enable. ...

Comment: To debug your code, you should be removing everything (commenting works) that does not cause the problem. Once you do that, you'll have a much shorter list of code. There are also breakpoints and `Debug.Log(string)` to print to the console.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Not exactly sure I get what you mean. I know for sure that my problem comes from deactivating the GameObject that has the coroutine attached. If I remove that, I get back to my initial issue, that the Countdown will be displayed under my pause menu (due to its transparency - which I would like to keep). I didn't find any reason to mention this, just because I'm looking for an answer on how to hide the object without (unintentionally) stopping the coroutine, or how to change the countdown's text alpha to 0 once the game is paused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Than you are starting a new Coroutine in `OnEnable` so everytime the GameObject is set to active again.

You should rather check if your countdown was finished before or not and only restart it if it was finished before.

Additionally you are not stopping the Coroutine when you pause note from [Coroutines:](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

> **Note**: Coroutines are **not** stopped when a [MonoBehaviour](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) is **disabled**, but only when it is definitely destroyed. You can stop a Coroutine using [MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html) and [MonoBehaviour.StopAllCoroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopAllCoroutines.html). Coroutines are also stopped when the [MonoBehaviour](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) is destroyed.

And since you are using `Time.timeScale = 0f;` to pause you should use [WaitForSecondsRealtime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSecondsRealtime.html) for waiting which isn't affected by the `Time.timeScale`

```
public Color color3;     
public Color color2;
public Color color1;

private Text countdown; 

// moved this to outer scope in order to
// "share" it among routines   
int count = 3;
// flag to control whether the last countdown was finished
private bool countdownFinished = true;    

private void Awake()
{
    // do this only once
    countdown = GetComponent<Text>();
}

private void OnEnable()
{
    countdown.text = count.ToString();        
    StartCoroutine(Countdown());
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    // just to be sure cancel all running Coroutines
    // should be done anyway automatically
    StopAllCoroutines();
}

private IEnumerator Countdown()
{
    // only restart the countdown if it was finished before
    // otherwise continue the last one
    if (countdownFinished) count = 3;

    countdownFinished = false;

    // inverting that for loop would make things a lot
    // easier for you
    while (count > 0)
    {
        countdown.text = count.ToString();

        // better use a switch for that         
        switch (count)
        {
            case 3:
                countdown.color = color3;
                break;

            case 2:
                countdown.color = color2;
                break;

            case 1:
                countdown.color = color1;
                break;
        }

        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);
        count--;
    }

    countdownFinished = true;
    StartRound();
}
```

Result: Continues if countdown didn't finish before disabling, otherwise starts a new countdown.

[image]

for the example I just did

```
private void StartRound()
{
    countdown.text = "GO!";
}
```

---

Instead of that switch you could also simply use a

```
public List<Color> colors = new List<Color>();
```

add your colors to the list (the most top one beeing color1, the most bottom one beeing color3) and than simply use

```
countdown.color = colors[count -1];
```

Comment: Cheers for this, especially for the `switch` (had a feeling this could be achieved in a more elegant way), unfortunately it doesn't help with my issue, the coroutine will still be restarted as I'm hiding the GameObject.

Comment: so wait .. after the countdown was finished once you don't want to show it again at all?

Comment: I want to pause it when pressing the Pause button (say it was at 2 seconds left) and resume (from where it left off) when Unpausing (resume from 2 seonds, rather than restarting from 3 each time). The struggle is with the from where it left off part.

Comment: Sorry I noticed we never have set a new value to `count` actually but only reduced `i` inside the loop. Fixed it now so it should do it now ;)

Comment: Tried this and now, when resuming, the Countdown doesn't come back at all and just hangs there; it's technically still in the Countdown stage, but no numbers show up; I can still pause the game.

Comment: How exactly do you unpause? I noticed you set `Time.timeScale = 0f;` so `WaitForSeconds` will be affected by this as well ... you could try `WaitForSecondsRealtime` instead

Comment: On second tinkering with my GameObject "hiding" in my PauseMenu script, it works. Thank you so much. Tried `WaitForSecondsRealtime` as well, but it doesn't seem to affect it in any way. Side question if I may: how did you add that GO! in your countdown? Are you counting from 4 and GO! is actually 1, or are you adding it somehow after the normal 321 countdown?

Comment: Scratch that last question. Seen the explanation in your answer now. :) Cheers.

Comment: @obsssve_cmplsve glad to help :) Did it work out in the end?

Comment: Like a charm. Thank you very much.